# Azure DevOps YAML stage template

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two environments, preprod and prod and they are pretty much the same.

So I created an yaml file, InfurstructureTemplate.yaml

```
parameters:
  xxxx
  jobs:
    - job: provision_job
```

I want to use this template for my two environments, here is what in mind:

```
stages:
- stage: PreProd Environment
- template: InfurstructureTemplate.yaml
- parameters:
      xxxx

- stage: Prod Environment
- template: InfurstructureTemplate.yaml
- parameters:
      xxxx
```

Is this the right way to use yaml template? When I googled this, seems template is on Stages level and you can't put it on stage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do it very similar, put the `template` in the `jobs`:

```
stages:
  - stage: PreProd_Environment
    displayName: PreProd Environment
    jobs:
      - template: InfurstructureTemplate.yaml
        parameters:
          projectDir: xxx

  - stage: Prod_Environment
    displayName: Prod Environment
    dependsOn: [ PreProd_Environment ]
    jobs:
      - template: InfurstructureTemplate.yaml
        parameters:
          projectDir: xxx
```

Comment: I see. Let me try this

Answer (score 1):

You may try this too as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/stages-template?view=azure-pipelines)

```
stages:
- template: InfurstructureTemplate.yaml
  parameters:
      xxxx

- template: InfurstructureTemplate.yaml
  parameters:
      xxxx
```